# How to distribute pods to all nodes evenly

Tags: kubernetes

I have three nodes and have pod replica 9. When I am trying to deploy,  Pods are unevenly scheduled on nodes.

How can I make sure that Pods are evenly scheduled on three nodes?

Answer (score 2):

You should configure [topology spread constraints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/). These control how pods are scheduled across your Kubernetes cluster based on regions, zones, nodes.

For spreading across nodes, you could use *maxSkew* (maxSkew describes the degree to which Pods may be unevenly distributed)

```
spec:
  topologySpreadConstraints:
    - maxSkew: 1
      topologyKey: node
      whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
```